calculating SVG viewBox angle of incidence for multiple reflections if origin and final points are known
I’d like to animate a bounce effect inside an SVG viewbox where the initial and final coordinates are known and keeping the angles of incidence equal.
I was able to calculate the coordinates for one bounce based on the example provided in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113359/how-to-find-angle-of-reflected-ray-to-match-a-point
I’d like to have the svg element bounce two or three times before arriving at the final coordinates.
For example, if I have an SVG viewBox 10 x 10, and points at p0_x = 7, p0_y = 6 and p1_x=2, p1_y = 3, and the refection points are r0_x = 10 and r1_y=10, can r0_y and r1_x be calculated such that the angels of incidence are equal?
From the above tank game example, it would be like adding a second set of triangles prime rotated 90 degrees, so that rotated side A’ = D, rotated P’ = 10-p0_y, and rotated C’ = B.
Is it possible to solve for A’ and C’ (or D and B), if P, P’, A and B’ are known?
Based on the above example, it looks to me like,
A’ =  B’ * P’ / D’  –  B’
and
D = B * P / (A + B)
and A’ = D, so
B’ * P’ / D’  –  B’ =  B * P / (A + B)
D’ can also be defined in terms of of C’ and P’ as D’ = P’ – C’
It seems there should be a unique set of coordinates r0_y and r1_x that keep the angles of incidence a’ = b’ and a = b.
And if it’s possible to solve for two, I think it should be possible to solve for three points of reflection.
Thanks!
From the post sited above:
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/M2uitApB.jpg

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Treat line $\ell: x = 10$ as a mirror, reflect $p_1 = (2,3)$ to $p'_1 = (18,3)$. The line thru $p_0 = (7,6)$ and $p'_1$ intersect  $\ell$ at $r_0 = (10,\frac{57}{11})$. This is the first reflection point you seek. For high order reflection points, reflecting $p_1$ to appropriate places, drawing straight lines and intersect it with the four lines $x = 0$,$x = 10$,$y = 0$ and $y = 10$.

Thanks.  This is an elegant solution.  I've been able to get it to work for two points of reflection off of the lines x=0,x=10,y=0 and y=10 in any direction.  What is the correct line to use for intermediate points of reflection between points on the lines  x=0,x=10,y=0 and y=10 when p0 and p1 are not the beginning or ending point?  I tried drawing lines between p0' and p1' points mirrored outside of the 10 x 10 viewBox, but these didn't intersect the lines x=0,x=10,y=0 and y=10 at the correct points.  Thanks again.
